# Stackdriver increased interval

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Is it possible to increase/change the frequency of the data that is collected by Stackdriver?

I am running Jenkins in a GKE cluster and am getting an error `ERROR: missing workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/`. I am trying to determine if the node it is running on is running out of resources but the build takes less than two minutes so I only get a single point of data regarding the node.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, although it requires you to customise fluentd. Specifically you may need to change the fluentd configuration in the monitoring sidecar.

There is some information on customising fluentd [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver.md#configuring-stackdriver-logging-agents).

As for the error you are receiving, I don't believe it is related to the node running out of resources. I feel it is a jenkins specific issue, as other users have reported the same error [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44659) .